# How do I resolve the actual type for a generic return type using reflection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have an **interface** with a **method with a generic return type**, and at runtime some instances of classes which indirectly implement that interface. Now I want to find out the **actual return type** for each implementation using reflection.

(*My idea is to use this mechanism to define a strategy using an interface, and find a matching strategy (specific return type) out of a set of strategy implementations at runtime, without having to introduce redundant helper methods which expose the type*).

To be more specific, let's consider following scenario:

```
private interface DAO <I extends Serializable, E> {

    public E getById (I id);
}

private abstract class AbstractDAO <T> implements DAO<Integer, T> {

    @Override
    public T getById (Integer id) {
        // dummy implementation, just for this example
        return null;
    }
}

private class PersonDAO extends AbstractDAO<Person> {
}

private class PersonDAOExtension extends PersonDAO {
}
```

At runtime, I want to find out for a given class (`PersonDAOExtension.class`) which type will be returned for the method `getById(..)` (expected to be: `Person.class`).

Using reflection, I can find out which generic `Type` is returned from this method. In this case, it's a `TypeVariable` (but could also be a `Class`, if any class in the hierarchy would specify a covariant return type):

```
Method method = PersonDAOExtension.class.getMethod("getById", Integer.class);
Type genericReturnType = method.getGenericReturnType();
if (genericReturnType instanceof TypeVariable<?>) {
    TypeVariable<?> typeVariable = (TypeVariable<?>) genericReturnType;
    typeVariable.getName(); //results in "T"
}
```

I assume resolving the actual type would mean recursing into superclasses and interfaces and translate the *raw* (`parameterizedType.getRawType()`) and *actual* (`parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()`) type arguments for any parameterized type, until the desired type name is found.

Has anyone done this before, and maybe some code snippets ready which will help me achieve this? Many thanks in advance :)

---

**Hint:** I was able to extract following information at runtime using reflection, so the raw and actual type information is retained:

```
private abstract interface DAO<I, E>
private abstract class AbstractDAO<T> extends Object implements DAO<Integer, T> [raw type:DAO<I, E>]
private class PersonDAO extends AbstractDAO<Person> [raw type:AbstractDAO<T>]
private class PersonDAOExtension extends PersonDAO
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the type, once you know it? If you're planning on using `instanceof` operator you could do instead `if (Person.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getReturnType())) { ... }`

Comment: The (non-generic) return type is Object, so this would always return false...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was finally able to find a solution, recursing into super classes and interfaces, replacing type variables with the type arguments passed until reaching the desired base class:

```
 /**
 * Resolves the actual generic type arguments for a base class, as viewed from a subclass or implementation.
 * 
 * @param <T> base type
 * @param offspring class or interface subclassing or extending the base type
 * @param base base class
 * @param actualArgs the actual type arguments passed to the offspring class
 * @return actual generic type arguments, must match the type parameters of the offspring class. If omitted, the
 * type parameters will be used instead.
 */
public static <T> Type[] resolveActualTypeArgs (Class<? extends T> offspring, Class<T> base, Type... actualArgs) {

    assert offspring != null;
    assert base != null;
    assert actualArgs.length == 0 || actualArgs.length == offspring.getTypeParameters().length;

    //  If actual types are omitted, the type parameters will be used instead.
    if (actualArgs.length == 0) {
        actualArgs = offspring.getTypeParameters();
    }
    // map type parameters into the actual types
    Map<String, Type> typeVariables = new HashMap<String, Type>();
    for (int i = 0; i < actualArgs.length; i++) {
        TypeVariable<?> typeVariable = (TypeVariable<?>) offspring.getTypeParameters()[i];
        typeVariables.put(typeVariable.getName(), actualArgs[i]);
    }

    // Find direct ancestors (superclass, interfaces)
    List<Type> ancestors = new LinkedList<Type>();
    if (offspring.getGenericSuperclass() != null) {
        ancestors.add(offspring.getGenericSuperclass());
    }
    for (Type t : offspring.getGenericInterfaces()) {
        ancestors.add(t);
    }

    // Recurse into ancestors (superclass, interfaces)
    for (Type type : ancestors) {
        if (type instanceof Class<?>) {
            // ancestor is non-parameterized. Recurse only if it matches the base class.
            Class<?> ancestorClass = (Class<?>) type;
            if (base.isAssignableFrom(ancestorClass)) {
                Type[] result = resolveActualTypeArgs((Class<? extends T>) ancestorClass, base);
                if (result != null) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
            // ancestor is parameterized. Recurse only if the raw type matches the base class.
            ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
            Type rawType = parameterizedType.getRawType();
            if (rawType instanceof Class<?>) {
                Class<?> rawTypeClass = (Class<?>) rawType;
                if (base.isAssignableFrom(rawTypeClass)) {

                    // loop through all type arguments and replace type variables with the actually known types
                    List<Type> resolvedTypes = new LinkedList<Type>();
                    for (Type t : parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()) {
                        if (t instanceof TypeVariable<?>) {
                            Type resolvedType = typeVariables.get(((TypeVariable<?>) t).getName());
                            resolvedTypes.add(resolvedType != null ? resolvedType : t);
                        } else {
                            resolvedTypes.add(t);
                        }
                    }

                    Type[] result = resolveActualTypeArgs((Class<? extends T>) rawTypeClass, base, resolvedTypes.toArray(new Type[] {}));
                    if (result != null) {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // we have a result if we reached the base class.
    return offspring.equals(base) ? actualArgs : null;
}
```

Works like a charm:

```
resolveActualTypeArgs(PersonDAOExtension.class, DAO.class)
```

results in `Integer`, `Person`

```
resolveActualTypeArgs(AbstractDAO.class, DAO.class)
```

results in `Integer`, `T`

```
resolveActualTypeArgs(LinkedList.class, Iterable.class, String.class)
```

results in `String`

I can now use this to find out which of a given set of DAO implementations can read Persons:

```
List<DAO<?, ?>> knownDAOs = ...

for (DAO<?, ?> daoImpl : knownDAOs) {
    Type[] types = resolveActualTypeArgs(daoImpl.getClass(), DAO.class);
    boolean canReadPerson = types[1] instanceof Class<?> && Person.class.isAssignableFrom((Class<?>) types[1]);
}
```

And this works regardless of whether I pass a `new PersonDAOExtension()`, a `new PersonDAO()` or a `new AbstractDAO<Person>{}`.

Comment: Nice! FYI, I found a tiny library that provides similar functionality but in a more general way: [gentyref](https://code.google.com/p/gentyref/wiki/ExampleUsage). I gave it a shot just now to solve my problem (to more precisely resolve field types when a subclass narrows the generic type), and it seems quite promising. Generics have lots of corner cases and I don't think gentyref covers all of them, but it is a great start.

Comment: Just tested with swapped generic arguments (`interface CrazyMap<K, V> extends Map<V, K>`) It works! Incredible. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

I was able to determine the generic return type of a method in one line using Google Guava's [TypeToken](https://guava.dev/releases/28.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html) class:

```
TypeToken.of(PersonDAOExtension.class)
        .resolveType(PersonDAOExtension.class.getMethod("getById", Integer.class).getGenericReturnType())
        .getRawType()
```

Alternatively, if you want to get the generic type of a class (as you did in your accepted answer), rather than the return type of a method, you could do the following:

```
TypeToken.of(PersonDAOExtension.class)
        .resolveType(AbstractDAO.class.getTypeParameters()[0])
        .getRawType()
```

Both of these solutions return `Person.class` as expected.

From your comments on the accepted answer, it looks like you just want to know whether the given DAO can accept `Person` objects. This too is doable with the API:

```
(new TypeToken<DAO<?, Person>>() {})
        .isSupertypeOf(TypeToken.of(PersonDAOExtension.class))
```

There is a decent explanation of the capabilities of this and other Guava reflection utilities [on the Guava GitHub wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained#typetoken).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before. In my solution the abstract class had a method named

`static void register(Class<? extends DAO> clazz, ? extends DAO daoInstance)`.

And in the abstract class I had a `Map` which stored references to the instances. I used singletons but you can use a multimap if you have multiple instances. Using this technique you can get rid of reflection and you will have a `Set` of all implementations which you registered and their classes as well.

You can also register some pojo class as well if you need more information:

```
public class DaoData{

    private Class<? extends DAO> daoClass;
    private Class<?> someArbitraryTypeClass;
    // ...
}
```

`static void register(DaoData daoData, ? extends DAO daoInstance)`

I know that it is not the best solution but it was simple and get the job done.

Comment: What's the return type of that method named register?

Comment: I think it was `void`.